# Why the pattern mismatch occurs?

Tags: java, regex

While trying to match the following pattern :

```
String regex_2 = "w+ w+ [d-]{10}";
System.out.println("Dev Anand 98-76-543210".matches(regex_2));
```

I get `false` as output. Why is that ?

Comment: Maybe you mean `\\w+ \\w+ [d-]{10}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match a digit, you need `\d`, not `d` in the character class. Likewise, you also need `\w` instead of `w` to match "word" characters. Finally, your number is 12 characters long (10 digits plus two dashes), not 10. Put it together, and this should work:

```
String regex_2 = "\\w+ \\w+ [\\d-]{12}";
System.out.println("Dev Anand 98-76-543210".matches(regex_2));
```

(Note that the `\` needs to be doubled when part of a Java string literal so that a single `\` ends up in the string. Same goes for character literals: `'\\'` is a single `\` character.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `\`s to indicate [predefined character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which in turn require `\\`s in the string literal, since [`\` is the escape character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) in Java strings.

```
String regex_2 = "\\w+ \\w+ [\\d-]{10}";
```

Additionally, [`String#matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) returns `true` [iff the *entire* pattern matches, not just part of it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29), so you either need to use a different method (such as [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29))

```
Pattern.compile("\\w+ \\w+ [\\d-]{10}")
    .matcher("Dev Anand 98-76-543210")
    .find(); // true
```

or a different pattern:

```
"Dev Anand 98-76-543210".matches("\\w+ \\w+ [\\d-]{12}"); // true
```

http://ideone.com/Bn82cF

Comment: `-` doesn't mean `hyphen` here ? I guess it does

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String regex_2 = "\\w+ \\w+ [\\d-]{12}";
```

you were matching only 10 of the them whereas including those two `-` there are 12

Comment: Maybe somebody though your answer was plagiarism from TedHopp's.

Comment: well, it looks like somebody else was faster than you =\

Comment: yeah that may be... but that doesnt make one to downvote an answer

Comment: Relax; it's just a downvote. The title text for the downvote arrow specifically says "This answer is not useful" which I must agree with in this case. It is not useful because it adds nothing which was not already available in other answers. Note, I was not the downvoter.